# Is it possible to force knifes only for the first round?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

Is it possible to configure a CS:GO server so that in the first round everyone is is forced to use knifes only (no pistols)?

If so, how?

Comment: It would be simple to do with a sourcemod plugin, if nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this is possible would be to use a plugin. Plugins can modify what is and isn't allowed on servers, so, for example, you could have someone freeze in their spot if they equip a gun on round one.

However, most likely nobody made a plugin for what you want yet, but if you make an account on **[these forums](http://forums.alliedmods.net/)**, and request a plugin, hopefully somebody can make a plugin suiting your needs.